# How to list user types from within a database and allow selection from an administration panel?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add an option in the backend of an administration panel where admins can change the user type. Called: `Change User Type`

Before these were the options available: `Add Notes about Driver` and  `Change Email`   :

[image]

I modified the php and added the front end selector to `Change user type` in the admin panel:

[image]

But the problem is that it keeps pulling a box to enter data. I want a list with all user types to be listed in a drop down so I can select a user type and change and not add notes to it.

In the database I only have three types of users "`user_group`". They are listed under Ids 1, 2, and 3.

**MY QUESTION IS**:
How can I make a drop down list appear, once I select `Change User Type` after already having selected the user under the `Select Driver` options in the previous drop down?

My user type ids are listed under `user_group`

[image]

Below is the current code on the file, which is not very much:

```
            function fn_ACTION_METHOD(sMethod){

                if(sMethod=='notes'){
                    document.getElementById('comment_box').style.display='block';
                    document.getElementById('email_box').style.display='none';
                    document.getElementById('btnSUBMIT').value='ADD NOTES';
                }else if(sMethod=='email'){
                    document.getElementById('comment_box').style.display='none';
                    document.getElementById('email_box').style.display='block';
                    document.getElementById('btnSUBMIT').value='CHANGE EMAIL';
                }else if(sMethod=='user_group'){
                    document.getElementById('comment_box').style.display='none';
                    document.getElementById('email_box').style.display='block';
                    document.getElementById('btnSUBMIT').value='ChangeType';
                }
            }
            function fn_LOAD_EMAIL(iDriverID){
                $.get("ajax_data.php", {action: 'load-email', did: iDriverID}, function(data){              
                            if (data=="ERROR"){
                                $('#Message').html("Error!!! in loading driver email");
                            }else{
                                $('#txtemail').val(data);
                            }
                }, 'html');
            }
            </script>

            </head>
            <body style="margin: 0px;">
            <div align="center">
                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <!--start header    -->
                    <? include('inc_header.php');   ?>

                    <!-- start side nav -->


                    <!-- actual page    -->
                    <td>
                    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="980">
                            <tr valign="top" align="left">
                                <td width="15" height="16"><img src="../assets/images/autogen/clearpixel.gif" width="15" height="1" border="0" alt=""></td>
                                <td width="1"><img src="../assets/images/autogen/clearpixel.gif" width="1" height="1" border="0" alt=""></td>
                                <td width="949"><img src="../assets/images/autogen/clearpixel.gif" width="683" height="1" border="0" alt=""></td>
                                <td width="15"><img src="../assets/images/autogen/clearpixel.gif" width="1" height="1" border="0" alt=""></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr valign="top" align="left">
                                <td height="40"></td>
                                <td colspan="2" width="949">
                                    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="949" style="background-image: url('../assets/images/banner.png'); height: 40px;">
                                        <tr align="left" valign="top">
                                            <td width="100%">
                                                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" height="100%">
                                                    <tr>            
                                                        <td class="TextObject" align="center">
                                                            <h1 style="margin-bottom: 0px;">DRIVER NOTES &amp; EMAIL CHANGE</h1>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr valign="top" align="left"><td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td></tr>
                            <tr valign="top" align="left"><td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td></tr>

                            <tr valign="top" align="left">
                                <td colspan="2"></td>
                                <td width="1050" class="TextObject" align="center">
                                    <form name="frm1" action="driver_notes_email.php" method="post">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add_action"   />
                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5" border="0" width="800" align="center" class="box">

                                            <tr><td colspan="2" id="Message" width="100%"><?=$sMessage?></td></tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="label" width="200">Driver:</td>
                                                <td width="800"><?  fn_DISPLAY_USERS('drpdriver', 0, "200", "1", "--Select Driver--", "CONCAT(l_name, ' ', f_name) AS user_name", "l_name", $iGROUP_DRIVER.",".$iGROUP_COORDINATOR_STAFF, "fn_LOAD_EMAIL(this.value);");?></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="label">Action:</td>
                                                <td>

                                                       <div class="left"><input type="radio" id="opttype" name="optaction" value="ChangeType" onClick="fn_ACTION_METHOD('notes');"/></div>
                                                    <span class="label left">Change User Type</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;


                                                    <div class="left"><input type="radio" id="optnotes" name="optaction" value="Notes" onClick="fn_ACTION_METHOD('notes');"/></div>

                                                    <span class="label left">Add Notes about Driver</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                    <input type="radio" id="optreading" name="optaction" value="Change Email" onClick="fn_ACTION_METHOD('email');"/>


                                                    <span class="label">Change Email</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                                                    </td>

                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="2">
                                                    <div id="email_box" style="display:none;">
                                                        <table  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td class="label" width="200">Email:</td>
                                                                <td width="400"><input type="text" id="txtemail" name="txtemail" value="" maxlength="150" style="width:250px;"  /></td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="2">
                                                    <div id="comment_box" style="display:none; width:100%;">
                                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5" border="0" width="100%">                                             
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td class="label" valign="top" width="200">Notes:</td>
                                                                <td width="400"><textarea name="txtcomments" id="txtcomments" cols="50" rows="10" style="width:250px;" ></textarea></td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>






                                            <tr><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>
                                            <tr><td></td><td><input type="button" name="btnSUBMIT" id="btnSUBMIT" value="ACTION" class="Button" onClick="valid_action(this.form);" style="width:150px;" /></td></tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </form>
                                </td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>


                    <!-- end actual page    -->

                  <!-- footer   -->
                  <? include('inc_footer.php'); ?>
                 </table>
                </td>
               </tr>
              </table>
             </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: You posted a question earlier that got downvoted because it was unclear. Now you post _a lot_ of code with a quite unclear question. You should define down the actual question, write it clearer and post _only_ the _relevant_ code.

Comment: Alright.. will try it again. Editing would not suffice?

Comment: Sure. Edit away. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some guides.

Comment: I edited and removed around 5,000 characters

Comment: Step one, redo your markup. People stopped using tables for layouts around 10 years ago. They are messy and a pain to work with. Search for some good CSS/CSS3 tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

Look in your html code where the div id equals email_box. This box is already on the page but is hidden. In your javascript you added for the 'change user type' you correctly changed the action button but you are still just showing the email_box div by calling style display = block

You need to add a new div which is hidden by default with a select box in it, and only show it when the radio button is clicked.  You will also need to add your php code in to actually update the user when the form is submitted.